# Detail textField overlapping

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a small detail *JasperReports*'s report developed with *iReport*. I have the classic *Header* band and well a row with the values, but below I need to put another textField which is in fact very long up to 500 characters namely *Observations*. In the *Detail* row one field can have up to 100 characters (namely *CONCEPT*) which can cause textField stretch vertically this is working OK. The problem appears when the *Concept* textField grows vertically the *Observations* which is below the *Detail* row stays in the same positions cause both **to overlap each other...**

Here is some picture of the results so far.

My report has following design (view in *iReport*):

[image]

And the generated report look like this:

[image]

As you can see the *Observations* textField if overlapping the wrap line of the *CONCEPTO* textField.

**UPDATE** after following the tips from `Alex K` i am receving this output....

[image]

Here is the code of *Detail* band:

```xml
<detail>
<band height="36" splitType="Stretch">
    <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
       <reportElement x="349" y="0" width="61" height="19"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{c04}+"€"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
        <reportElement x="410" y="0" width="53" height="19"/>
        <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
        <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{c05}+"€"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
        <reportElement x="240" y="-1" width="57" height="20"/>
        <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
        <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{c06}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
        <reportElement x="68" y="0" width="172" height="19"/>
        <textElement/>
        <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{c03}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement x="297" y="0" width="51" height="19"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{c02}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="0" width="67" height="19"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{c07}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="1" y="18" width="554" height="18"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{c08}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set *isStretchWithOverflow* property as **true** for *textField* with long text (contains `$F{c03}` field in your case) and this properties for *textField* in the second row (contains `$F{c08}` field in your sample):

- *positionType* with **Float** value;
- *stretchType* with **No stretch** value;
- *isStretchWithOverflow* with **true** value for support long text.

#### The sample

The *jrxml* file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="overlapping_test" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="c07" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="c03" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="c02" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="c04" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="c05" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="c08" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="92" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[Code]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="92" y="0" width="92" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[Concept]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="184" y="0" width="92" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[Candidate]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="276" y="0" width="92" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[Price]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="368" y="0" width="92" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[Amount]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="40" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="92" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{c07}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement x="92" y="0" width="92" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{c03}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="184" y="0" width="92" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{c02}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="276" y="0" width="92" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{c04}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="368" y="0" width="92" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{c05}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="20" width="460" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{c08}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

The report's design in *iReport*:

[image]

And the result (via preview in *iReport*):

[image]

Comment: should i set isStretchWithOverflow=false and stretchType="no strech" on the second row? $F{c08}?

Comment: @chiperortiz You should set *stretchType* as **No stretch** for textField for `$F{c08}` field